# Extract submap from a map that contains only duplicate values

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I'm searching for an optimal or subpotimal solution for below problem:

**Hp:** We have a Java8 Map:
Map<Integer, Object>: {**0 -> object0**, **1 -> object0**, 2->object1, ...., n->objectN}

**Goal:**
Solution to return a Map (a submap) that contains only key,value elements of original map with same objects:
Map<Integer, Object>: {**0 -> object0**, **1 -> object0**}

I found a solution to get a List of duplicate but I don't find a solution to get a new Map with only duplicated values.

Thanks for support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```java
Map<Object, Map<String, Object>> subMaps = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                           toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

This will return you a map of maps.

So if you want the submap containing only `object0` do this:

```java
Map<String, Object> subMap = subMaps.get(object0);
```

---

If you are not interested in all the submaps, but looking for a specific value, then do this instead:

```java
Map<String, Object> subMapForObject1 = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .filter(e -> object1.equals(e.getValue());
       .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution would be:

1. Build a temporary inverted map `Map<Object, List<Integer>>`
2. Filter the inverted map to keep only duplicates
3. Use `flatMap` to restore initial `Map<Integer, Object>`

```java
Map<Integer, Object> map = Map.of(
    0, "object0", 1, "object0", 2, "objectA", 3, "objectZ", 4, "objectZ"
);
System.out.println(map);

Map<Integer, Object> filtered = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
            ))
            .entrySet().stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Object, List<Integer>>>
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1) // keep duplicates
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> Map.entry(v, e.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println(filtered);
```

Output:

```
{0=object0, 1=object0, 2=objectA, 3=objectZ, 4=objectZ}
{0=object0, 1=object0, 3=objectZ, 4=objectZ}
```

---

**Update**

Simpler solution by @Andreas suggestion would be:

```java
Map<Integer, Object> filtered2 = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .entrySet().stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Object, List<Map.Entry<Integer, Object>>>
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1) // keep duplicates
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println(filtered2);
```

Output is the same as above:

```
{0=object0, 1=object0, 3=objectZ, 4=objectZ}
```

Comment: I'd recommend just adding the map entries as the values of the temporary map. No need to call `mapping(getKey(), ...`, and no need for the `Map.entry(...)` helper method that didn't even exist before Java 9.

Comment: Right, thanks for the suggestion, updated the answer

Comment: `map(v -> v)`??